# Recover Riemannian metric from volume form

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

If I know a Riemannian volume form on a Riemannian manifold, then is it always possible to recover the Riemannian metric which induces that volume?

Comment: No, e.g. $dx^2/a^2+a^2dy^2$ has the same volume form as $dx^2+dy^2$.

Comment: Are there any assumptions (besides dimension =1) that make this hold?  What if I assume translation invariance?

Comment: The above counter-example still works.

Comment: Thought so.  ok cool thanks

Comment: Even worse: Given any two diffeomorphic compact Riemannian manifolds of the same volume, there exists a volume-form preserving diffeomorphism between these manifolds (Moser's theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intrinsic volume form is given by $\left|\det G\right|^{1/2}$, where $G$ is the matrix representation of the metric $g$, i.e. $G:=\left(g_{ij}\right)$ where $g_{ij} := g\left(X_i,X_j\right)$, and $X_k$ are coordinate vector fields.

Metrics $g$ and $g'$ with matrices $G$ and $G'$ with $\left|\det G\right| = \left| \det G' \right|$ will have the same volume form.